# How to I delete my Gmail photo

Tags: gmail, google-account-profile

I only want my photo to show for my blog; is that possible? How do I delete it from appearing in my Gmail emails?

Answer (score 3):

Gmail → *Settings* (cog gear in the upper-right corner) → *General* → *My picture* → *Change Picture* → Select **No picture**.